# AJAX: Bootstrap Typeahead: Unexpected Token Error

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, syntax-error

I'm getting unexpected token error on the first letter of what is in my document.

```
$('#typeahead').typeahead({
source: function (typeahead, query) {
    return $.post('ajax/page.php', { query: query }, function (data) {
        alert(data);
        return typeahead.process(JSON.parse(data));
    });
}
});
```

In my page.php:

```
<?php 
        $array[] = array("test","treat","food");
        $json = json_encode($array);
        echo "<script>var query = ".$json.";</script>";
?>
```

So with this code, I get an error with `Uncaught Syntax: Unexpected token <`

So when I remove `<script></script>` so it'll just `echo "var query=".$json.";"`, I get `Uncaught Syntax: Unexpected token v`.

So I'm assuming it'll just keep giving me unexpected token of the first letter that is being echo'd out of page.php

Can someone tell me what is wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#typeahead').typeahead({
source: function (query, process) {
    return $.post('ajax/page.php', { query: query }, function (data) {
        process(JSON.parse(data));
    });
}
});

//page.php
$array = array("test","treat","food");
echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: this gives me `process not defined`, so I did `return typeahead.process(data)` and it just returns the first letter repeats that letter a few times.

Comment: which version of boostrap you use? In Version 2.2.2 (latest) all works. Working demo: http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/410520/trash.7z

Comment: Awesome! It worked! I forgot to change the paramteres `(query,process)`. Also, I had to remove the `[]` from `$array[]`. Why is that? Thanks!

Comment: $array = array(); - declares array $array[] = array(); declares two - dimensional array

Comment: thanks, that makes sense. 1 last quick question, if you don't mind, is it possible to customize the way it drops down? Like add rows or more text/images from a multi dimensional array? Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/2441 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873312/how-to-customize-bootstrap-typeahead-layout-function-for-more-than-just-text